# How to Welcome Popup with Some Offer?

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi i try to create a New Popup for first time user entering

With Some offers [image]

Above image attached

Comment: any plugin or module tell me

Comment: do  you know how to create simple popup ?

Comment: i don't know, help me

Comment: Check this out `https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-subscription-with-free-gift-coupon-popup.html`, This is the best popup for Subscription with a gift.

Comment: hire a good developer then

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-s‌​ubscription-with-fre‌​e-gift-coupon-popup.‌​html URL Not Working i am getting 404 page error

Comment: Use this key in your Magento connect for above module. -> `http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/ES_Newssubscribers`

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-subscription-with-free-gift-coupon-popup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create a Custom Module for popup in Magento 1.9 or below versions:

Add following code to    `app/code/local/Codemazes/NewsletterPopUp/etc/config.xml(create the path)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config>
      <modules>
            <Codemazes_NewsletterPopUp>
                  <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Codemazes_NewsletterPopUp>
      </modules>
      <frontend>
            <layout>
                  <updates>
                        <newsletterpopup>
                              <file>newsletterpopup.xml</file>
                        </newsletterpopup>
                  </updates>
            </layout>
      </frontend>
</config>
```

And then add your module file in `app/etc/modules/Codemazes_NewsletterPopUp.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
          <modules>
                <Codemazes_NewsletterPopUp>
                      <active>true</active>
                      <codePool>local</codePool>
                </Codemazes_NewsletterPopUp>
          </modules>
    </config>

then add layout file to your layout folder in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourdesign/layout/newsletterpopup.xml`

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- These 2 below should already be included by Magento, but if not, you need to put them here -->
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <!-- This line adds our newsletter template at the end of your site's body, remember to replace 'val' to match your folder path -->
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="codemazes/newsletterpopup/newsletter-popup.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>

</layout>
```

now add a view file in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourdesign/template/codemazes/newsletterpopup/newsletter-popup.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var check_cookie = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('popup-shown'); ?>";
        var popup = jQuery('#newsletter-popup');
        setTimeout (function(){
                if(!check_cookie) {
                popup.show();
                <?php Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('popup-shown', 'true', '');?>
            }
        },5000);
        jQuery('.close_popup').click(function(){
            popup.fadeOut();
        });
    });
 </script>
<div id="newsletter-popup" class="container">
<span class="close_popup">X</span>
    <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="newsletter_content" style="float:left;">
                <h1>HELLO THERE!</h1>
                <p>SIGN UP TO GET UPDATE ABOUT OUR UPCOMING EVENTS AND SPECIAL DISCOUNT OFFERS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="register-form" style="float:right;">
                <form id="newsletter-registration-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new/') ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
                    <div class="form-fields-middle">
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input name="email" id="cm_email" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Your Email') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Your Email'" class="validate-email required-entry field-left" type="text" value="Enter Your Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-sign-up-now">
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-registration-form', true);
</script>
```

And edit the view file according to your needs. Happy Coding!

Comment: This is not your code. Original one is from here https://www.demacmedia.com/mini-tutorial-magento-newsletter-pop-up-with-cookie/

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friends I got Code

if you need use this

**app/design/frontend/default/bwell4ever/template/page/home.phtml**

***add your popup image in /var/www/bwell/skin/frontend/default/theme/images/BWellCode_1.jpg***
add below css and Javascript

```
.spl_img{
background-image: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/BWellCode_1.jpg') ?>);
background-size: 450px 450px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: none;

}

<div id="my-welcome-message" class="spl_img"></div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
        jQuery('#my-welcome-message').firstVisitPopup({
        cookieName : 'homepage',
        showAgainSelector: '#show-message'
        });
    });
 </script>
```